# How can I make a dockerfile which installs python3.7?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to install python3.7 with a docker image.

My code:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install wget gcc make software-properties-common -y
RUN wget http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/LibreSSL/libressl-2.1.6.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzvf libressl-2.1.6.tar.gz
RUN libressl-2.1.6/configure
RUN make
RUN make install
RUN ldconfig

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3.7 python3-pip -y
RUN pip3 install requests

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["python3", "./c3-assigner.py"]
```

When I run these codes individually on a terminal, python3.7 is successfully installed.

But when I make a docker image with this dockerfile, and run it, it seems to install python3.5.2

What could be missing in this dockerfile?

Thanks :)

Comment: instead of ubuntu:16.04 ,why dont you use python as a base image (https://hub.docker.com/_/python)

Comment: @Rezwan Yes, when I use python for that, I can use python3.7. But I also have to use Libressl, but for python image, openssl is installed as a default. So I thought it would be better to use ubuntu, instead of re-installing Libressl in a python image.

Comment: I think you need to set ur Home installation path, with ubuntu python 3.5 comes default. so both versions are there but it picks python3.5 as default. can u check your bashrc file for default version?